SPI control on raspberry pi 5 using vs2022/.NET 4.8
Would be most grateful for help - I'm trying to get SPI to work on my Raspberry pi 5 using .NET4.8 (Visual Studio 2022) in c# (I'm running my compiled code on the pi using Mono). It's currently not working as I have checked there's no SPI clock (constantly at zero volts) Looking at the Microsoft learn website, you have to tell the gpio pins to switch to alternative function to facilitate this. The code to do this is
SpiDevice.FromIdAsync() and you have to enter a BusId and "settings" as parameters. However, I can't find what the BusId is supposed to be, and no matter what I enter, even if I try to assign a name to the BusId, the intellisense won't accept anything and puts a a red line under whatever is entered, despite trying every one of the intellisense's recommended fixes.I have installed the correct Nuget packages and put in "using Windows.Devices.SPI" at the start of the program, which the intellisense recognises. See my code, I'd be grateful if someone could help me to sort this problem! I've had the SPI working as it should in Python so I know the problem isn't with the Pi itself. Has anyone here managed to get around this problem? If so, please put me right!
     // Use chip select line CS0
     
     var settings = new SpiConnectionSettings(0);
     String bus;
     object spi_bus0 = null;
     SpiDevice device = SpiDevice.FromIdAsync(spi_bus0, settings);
     
     // Set clock to 10M
     settings.ClockFrequency = 500000;
     //....

Having followed and implemented the kind advice from PMF, I have installed .NET6 on my pi 5. it transpires there are 2 problems, which it would appear is down to .NET : 1) Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 22. "Can not set SPI mode to Mode0".
2) "System.IO.IOException: Error 2. Can not open SPI device file '/dev/spidev1.0'."
I have checked the /dev directory on my Raspberry Pi os, and there is no spidev1.0, only spidev0.1 and spidev10. I have not been able to source spidev1.0 online, so I'm stumped until I can get help. Does anyone know if spidev1.0 is standard with an earlier version of Raspbian or Raspberry Pi os?  "PMF" asked that I post the code which DOES run the SPI in Python, here it is:...from   time import sleep
    import spidev
    import os
    import sys
    import termios
    import pygame  
    spiPort0 = spidev.SpiDev()
    spiPort0.open(0,0)
    spiPort0.max_speed_hz = 100000
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    
    def spiSendRecvOneByte(spiPort, sendByte):
        sendByteArray = [sendByte]
        recvByteArray = spiPort.xfer(sendByteArray)    
        return recvByteArray
    
    def repeatSendOneByte(spiPort, sendByte,    
        print('\nBegin repeatSendByte(),....')
        #for event in pygame.event.get():
         # if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          #  if event.key == pygame.K_q:
           #  sys.exit()
        for i in range(repeatCount):
            spiSendRecvOneByte(spiPort, sendByte)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pygame.K_q:
               sys.exit()

...here is the .NET c# code which results in errors and does not run the SPI clock:...
    using System.Device.Gpio;
    using System.Device.Spi;
    namespace Spi
    {
        public class Pmc1 
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SpiDevice spi = SpiDevice.Create(new SpiConnectionSettings(0)); 
                spi.WriteByte(0x42);
                var incoming = spi.ReadByte();
                //var settings = new SpiConnectionSettings(0);
                //spi.ClockFrequency = 50000;
            }
        }
    }

I'm aware that ClockFrequency should be preceded by settings ie settings.ClockFrequency but this won't compile so I've remarked it out. However the default SPI clock should still run.
...and here is the resulting errors when run on the pi 5 under .NET6:...
    root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/SPI1# dotnet run
    Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 2. Can not open SPI device file '/dev/spidev1.0'.
       at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.Initialize()
       at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.WriteByte(Byte value)
       at Spi.Pmc1.Main(String[] args) in /home/pi    /SPI1/Program.cs:line 12
    root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/SPI1# nano Program.cs
    root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/SPI1# dotnet run
    Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 22. Can not set SPI mode to Mode0.
       at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.Initialize()
       at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.WriteByte(Byte value)
       at Spi.Pmc1.Main(String[].... 


If anyone else here has experienced this problem and knows a fix, I'd be most grateful for your help. Thanks Paul Clements and thanks to "PMF" without whose  help and advice I wouldn't have got this far.

Mono and .NET 4.8 is very old - is there a reason you can't run a more recent version of .NET?

Thanks Dai, I don't think that's the problem. The microsoft tutorial was actually aimed at .Net 2.1!! VS2022 seems to default to .net4.8. Can you advise me if there's something more modern/up to date than mono? I urgently need to get the SPI working! Many thanks, Paul

Can you share the link to this tutorial?

Dai here it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi

Oh, the article it says has a disclaimer that it's an old article...

yes it;s aimed at .net2.1 . Just hope someone can give me an answer as I'm getting frustrated with lack of info and help from Microsoft! With Python, everything works a dream, it's just too slow being an interpreted language!

Can you switch back to python and get working.  There is no reason to change any strapping when going between c# and python.  What configuration file are you using for python.  The c# settings and the python settings must be identical.  I suspect the settings in c# are wrong.  The settings have to be the same as the python settings.  I have worked with PI 5 and know the hardware very well.  Make voltage reading with Python and make sure they are correct.  It is possible that somethin disconnected after you got python working.

jdweng thanks, I'll check the settings in Python. I'm getting totally disillusioned with Microsoft for lack of help and information - typical, they are a corporate monster. I have little faith in ever getting my code working in c# thanks to insufficient information and the intellisense doing illogical things. Not only that, code which works in .Net2.1 will not work in 4.8, totally infuriating. I've been wasting time trying to solve this problem for days and days now.

"I have installed the correct Nuget packages". I doubt that, because Windows.Devices.SPI is really outdated and only for Windows 10 Iot, which is in itself completely outdated (and is not supported on the RPI5, anyway).
Assuming you're in fact running a version of Raspberry Pi OS, the correct package to use is System.Device.Gpio. Here is the documentation on how to use SPI with that package.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpiDevice spi = SpiDevice.Create(new SpiConnectionSettings(0));
            spi.WriteByte(0x42);
            var incoming = spi.ReadByte();
        }

Note: While the package is supported on Mono, I'd still recommend to use .NET 6.0 or later, as it is the modern runtime to run on linux.

thanks PMF I've tried it,  had to add System.Device.Spi  it compiles but still doesn't work - no SPI clock at all. I know I've set the Pi up properly becuase sure enough in Python, the SPI clock runs perfectly. I've seen and read/applied the code in the link you sent above also. Have you succeeded in getting SPI and the SPI clock to run on a Pi using Mono? Do you work for Microsoft? they need to provide an answer for this, it has totally frustrated me and no doubt many others.. I'm beginning to think the SPI simply can't be set up in c# with mono.

ps PMF many thanks for your help here, I WILL try your suggestion of .NET 6.0 as the spi problem could well be down to Mono not working properly, I saw someone else has a problem with it as they said on this site  just recently

I haven't used SPI that much, but I definitelly saw it working. Maybe there's some RPI5-specific thing that was missed. I don't own an RPI5, but I'll try to have this tested. Can you show the python code that works?

Hi and thanks PMF, I have taken your advice and installed .NET 6 on my pi 5. I have tried your code which I put into a small program (see the last part below); firstly, on compiling/running with "dotnet run" it responds with an error on setting up Spi 0, then when I replace the 0 with a 1, the error vanishes but it then responds with an error saying it can't find dev/spidev1.0. I checked the file structure in the /dev directory, and sure enough spidev1.0 isn't there, in my /dev directory, there is spidev0.1 and spidev10. I googled spidev1.0 but it doesn't seem to exist! So i'm totally stumped.

from   time import sleep
import spidev
import os
import sys
import termios
import pygame
spiPort0 = spidev.SpiDev()
spiPort0.open(0,0)
spiPort0.max_speed_hz = 100000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
def spiSendRecvOneByte(spiPort, sendByte):
sendByteArray = [sendByte]
recvByteArray = spiPort.xfer(sendByteArray)
return recvByteArray
def repeatSendOneByte(spiPort, sendByte, pauseTimeBetweenBytes, repeatCount):
print('\nBegin repeatSendByte(),....')

above is python code.

your code....I run it on the pi  with dotnet run, having downloaded/installed System.Device.Spi....using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Device.Spi;
namespace Spi
{
public class Pmc1
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
SpiDevice spi = SpiDevice.Create(new SpiConnectionSettings(0));
spi.WriteByte(0x42);
var incoming = spi.ReadByte();
//var settings = new SpiConnectionSettings(0);
//spi.ClockFrequency = 50000;
}
}
}

Here are the errors that I get back on doing dotnet run:

. System.IO.IOException: Error 2. Can not open SPI device file '/dev/spidev1.0'.
at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.Initialize()
at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.WriteByte(Byte value)
at Spi.Pmc1.Main(String[] args) in /home/pi/SPI1/Program.cs:line 12
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/SPI1# nano Program.cs
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/SPI1# dotnet run
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error 22. Can not set SPI mode to Mode0.
at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.Initialize()
at System.Device.Spi.UnixSpiDevice.WriteByte(Byte value)
at Spi.Pmc1.Main(String[]

@PaulClements Thanks, I'll try to take a look or report it to the relevant group. Meanwhile, please [edit] your question and add this information there instead of in the comments.

Thanks PMF, have edited the code as you directed. Would be really grateful for help in solving this issue!

I'm assuming the first error is because you selected bus 1 instead of 0. For the second error, I'll try to have it tested.

Hi PMF no, it simply wouldn't work with mode0 so that's why i changed to mode1. I think the problem all centres around .NET / c# requiring spidev1.0. As far as the SPI not working with code written in .NET4.8 is concerned, I suspect the problem with there is MONO not dealing with the SPI, because the code compiles. I wrote the .NET4.8 code in VS2022 community and then transferred the compiled .exe file to the pi and ran with MONO. Would be most grateful for your help on this! Many thanks.
